# How to add a prefix to each line using Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a string and would like to add a prefix to each line, resulting in a new string.

How can I do that using the new Java 8 syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a regex

```
static String appendPrefixToEachLine(String prefix, String s) {
    String ret = prefix + s.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "$1" + prefix);
    return ret.substring(0, ret.length() - prefix.length());
}
```

As @Holger mentions you can do this without a capturing group with

```
return prefix+s.replaceAll("(?:\r\n?|\n)(?!\\z)", "$0"+Matcher.quoteReplacement(prefix));
```

This regex says, find the places after a new line but not just before the end.

Comment: To mimic the standard behavior of line matching (like in `BufferedReader`), you should match a sole `\r` as well, so the pattern should be `\r\n?|\n`. Note that you don’t need braces when you use `$0` instead of `$1`. And I would quote the `prefix` using [`quoteReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement-java.lang.String-) to be safe. And if you append a negative look-ahead for the end of input to the pattern: `(?!\z)` you don’t need the `substring` operation.

Comment: Would using two groups in the regex be much slower? `return prefix + s.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)(.+)", "$1" + prefix + "$2");` Or is doing a single group replace followed by cleanup `substring` a better solution?

Comment: @flkes: as said, you can do entirely without capturing groups: `return prefix+s.replaceAll("(?:\r\n?|\n)(?!\\z)", "$0"+Matcher.quoteReplacement(prefix));` but I wouldn’t expect recognizable performance differences. After all, only `int`s holding the start and end are recorded for each group and regex always reserves store for at least ten groups (for whatever reason). What matters most is the amount of `char`s to be copied, so avoiding the `substring` operation is preferable, regardless of how many groups you need.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for a Java 8 solution, but it's not necessary to use any Java 8 features for this. Here's how I'd do it:

```
static String prefixLines(String prefix, String input) {
    return input.replaceAll(".*\\R|.+\\z", Matcher.quoteReplacement(prefix) + "$0");
}
```

I think matching entire lines (including a partial last line) makes things a bit easier than matching just line separators, as in [Peter Lawrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35707910/1441122). Still, +1 for that. Also, kudos to [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707760/how-to-add-a-prefix-to-each-line-using-java-8#comment59092749_35707910) for mentioning `quoteReplacement`, which is very easy to forget.

Note that I've used `\\R` which matches any Unicode line break. However, this doesn't match the behavior of `BufferedReader.readLine()` in case that's important.

Answer (score 1):

```
private String appendPrefixToEachLine(String prefix, String s) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    new BufferedReader(new StringReader(s)).lines()
            .map(line -> prefix + line + '\n')
            .forEach(stringBuilder::append);
    // Delete last added new line
    stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Instead of `\n`, you can use `System.lineSeparator()`.

Comment: Nice answer :) Let me +1

Comment: Optionally you could do `new StringJoiner(prefix, prefix, "")` and remove the call to `map`

Comment: @flkes: it’s rather `.collect(Collectors.joining('\n'+prefix, prefix, "\n"))`, but indeed, that’s better than dealing with `StringBuilder` manually here.

Comment: @Holger ahh right! I always forget about `Collectors::joining` !

Comment: Guys, the Collectors option sounds interesting. Do you want to add an answer with Collectors?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create the lines with the + operator on strings. This creates many unneccessary intermmediate instances of String. As you have a StringBuilder you can just append everything to it:

```
private String appendPrefixToEachLine(String prefix, String s) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    new BufferedReader(new StringReader(s)).lines()
            .forEach(line -> stringBuilder.append(prefix).append(line).append('\n'));
    // Delete last added new line
    stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
    return stringBuilder.toString();
```

}

Comment: It does not matter. Since java 6 you can use + operator because compiler internally supersede's it to StringBuilder...

Comment: @Gaskoin But it's a new StringBuilder for every line … not the one StringBuilder created at the beginning.

Comment: yup, true, too late for me:)

Answer (score 0):

```
private String appendPrefixToEachLine(String prefix, String s) {
    return new BufferedReader(new StringReader(s)).lines()
        .collect(Collectors.joining('\n'+prefix, prefix, ""));
}
```

Explanation: Collect all lines and join them with the provided delimiter.

Comment: This came out pretty nice :)

Answer (score 0):

If your string could have **any combination of line separators (\n or \r\n etc) and you need to keep it**. Also if you **do not want to prefix empty lines** this solution could be useful. It uses the new Java 8 API and does not use RegEx:

```
public static String prefixEachLine(String text, String prefix) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        Set<Character> endLineChars = Stream.of('\n', '\r').collect(Collectors.toSet());

        text.chars().forEach(ch -> {
            if (result.length() == 0 || (!endLineChars.contains((char) ch)
                    && endLineChars.contains(result.charAt(result.length() - 1)))) {
                result.append(prefix);
                result.append((char) ch);
            } else {
                result.append((char) ch);
            }
        });

        return result.toString();
    }
```